# Unable to understand the spacefree function in scullpipe driver

Tags: c, pointers, linux-device-driver

I am reading "Linux Device Drivers 3" and I am having trouble understanding the following code:

```
/* How much space is free */
static int spacefree(struct scull_pipe *dev){
  if(dev->rp == dev->wp)
     return dev->buffersize - 1;
  return ((dev->rp + dev->buffersize - dev->wp) % dev->buffersize) - 1;
}
```

Based on my understanding:
1. *buffer is the beginning of buffer.
2. *end is the ending of buffer.
3. end = buffer + buffersize
4. So, *buffersize* is the total size of the buffer.

```
if(dev->rp == dev->wp)
     return dev->buffersize - 1;
```

The above code is correct, *if* both the read pointer (rp) and write pointer (wp) are at the beginning of the buffer. Because if no data is written to the buffer, then the write pointer (wp) will be at the beginning of the buffer (unless the write pointer (wp) has wrapped), hence, the total amount of free space is equal to *buffersize*.

But I am not sure whether the above code is correct, if both the read pointer (rp) and write pointer (wp) point to the end of the buffer (or point to a memory location in the middle of the buffer). If the write pointer (wp) points to the end of the buffer, then the total amount of free space should be *0*, right?

```
return ((dev->rp + dev->buffersize - dev->wp) % dev->buffersize) - 1;
```

Based on my understanding, the above code should return the total amount of free space in the buffer *when* the read pointer (rp) and write pointer (wp) *do not* point to the same memory location in the buffer.

Shouldn't it be possible to calculate the total amount of free space based on the location of the write pointer (wp) alone?

For ex: dev->end - dev->wp

Can someone please explain this code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood the code:

1. The buffer is circular.
2. After the data is read from a memory location, the data (in the memory location) is cleared. So all memory locations before the read pointer (rp) and after the write pointer (wp) will be empty.
3. If the read pointer (rp) and the write pointer (wp) point to the same memory location, then the buffer is empty.
4. If the write pointer (wp) is present right behind the read pointer, then the buffer is full.

   `return ((dev->rp + dev->buffersize - dev->wp) % dev->buffersize) - 1;`

To understand the above code snippet:

Consider a circular buffer with 10 memory locations:

```
 8 9 10 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

If the read pointer (rp) is at memory location 3 and the write pointer is at memory location 7, then 5 memory locations are free:

```
8, 9, 10, 1, 2
```

Plugging in the values:

`return ((dev->rp + dev->buffersize - dev->wp) % dev->buffersize) - 1;`

`return ((3 + 10 - 7) % 10) -1`

`return ((6) % 10) -1`

`return 6-1`

`return 5`